# How to measure Down time for VM migration

Tags: kvm, qemu, migration, cloud

I am using KVM with virt-manager to migrate the virtual machines from one system to another.
VM Migraiton is successfully done and migration time is measured correctly. Now, I am stuck for how to measure downtime.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to see when a system is stopped but `dmesg -w` will show something when you resume your system.

The best way might be having a logger running ind a console:

```
while : ; do sleep 1 ; date +%FT%T >> downtime.log ; done
```

and then look for missing logging.

You can also calculate downtime at the same time:

```
while : ; do sleep 1 ; NEW=$(date +%s) ; echo $(date +%FT%T) $((NEW-LST)) >> downtime.log ; LST=$NEW ; done
```

It is a bit longer so use a script:

```
#! /bin/bash
LST=$(date +%s)
while : ; do
  sleep 1
  NEW=$(date +%s)
  echo $(date +%FT%T) $((NEW-LST)) >> downtime.log
  LST=$NEW
done
```